# Increase and decrease button in addtocart.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

This is my file:

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<?php $buttonTitle = $this->__('Add to Cart'); ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <div class="product-pricing">
        <?php echo $this->__('This product is available for purchase in increments of %s only.', /**$this->getProductName(),*/ $this->getProductDefaultQty()) ?>
    </div>
    <div class="add-to-cart">
        <?php if(!$_product->isGrouped()): ?>
            <div class="qty" style="display: inline-flex">
                <label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
                <a class="decrement_qty" href="javascript:void(0)" >
                    <i class="fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" >
                    </i>
                </a>
                <input id="qty" class="input-text qty" type="text" title="Qty" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" maxlength="12" name="qty" />
                <a class="increment_qty" href="javascript:void(0)">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus-circle fa-lg" aria-hidden="true" ></i>
                </a>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" id="product-addtocart-button" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true) ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.increment_qty').click(function() {
        var oldVal = jQuery(this).parent().find("input").val();
        if ( parseFloat(oldVal) >= 1 ) {
            var newVal = parseFloat(oldVal) + 1;
            jQuery(this).parent().find("input").val(newVal);
        }
    });

    jQuery('.decrement_qty').click(function() {
        var oldVal = jQuery(this).parent().find("input").val();
        if ( parseFloat(oldVal) >= 2 ) {
            var newVal = parseFloat(oldVal) - 1;
            jQuery(this).parent().find("input").val(newVal);
        }
        });
    });
//]]>
</script>
```

This is the result.

[image: risultato]

But it increment-decrement vaule by only 1.

My question is:
Can I increase or decrease the quantity of the qty_increments value set in the inventory of the product?

[image: qty_increments]

In this case I need to increase or decrease by 500.

Thanks and your suggestions

Comment: you want to increment by 500 for each click, exemple 500, 1000, 1500 ... ?

Comment: For this product are 500. In fact if I change +1 or -1 in "var newVal = parseFloat (oldVal) + or - 1" in + or - 500, it works. But for another product is another value I put into the inventory - "qty increments". I've put the back-end screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this can be done by modifying the 1 within javascript to echo $_product->getStockItem()->getData('qty_increments')

**e.g.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('.increment_qty').click(function() {
    var oldVal = jQuery(this).parent().find("input").val();
    if ( parseFloat(oldVal) >= 1 ) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldVal) + <?php echo $_product->getStockItem()->getData('qty_increments'); ?>;
        jQuery(this).parent().find("input").val(newVal);
    }
});

jQuery('.decrement_qty').click(function() {
    var oldVal = jQuery(this).parent().find("input").val();
    if ( parseFloat(oldVal) >= 2 ) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldVal) - <?php echo $_product->getStockItem()->getData('qty_increments'); ?>;
        jQuery(this).parent().find("input").val(newVal);
    }
    });
});
//]]>
</script>
```

This is not tested but have seen it used: https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/Get-product-quantity-increments-on-Product-view-page/m-p/53475#M6765

Comment: IT WORKS. It would take some remodeling to correct some minor problems, but it may be fine.
I had found that solution, but having only the basics of php and java, I had tried inserting it but with catastrophic results.

Comment: Awesome glad you have sorted it!

Comment: I changed the line "if (parseFloat (oldVal)> = 1) {" in "if (parseFloat (oldVal)> = 0) {" otherwise if with the - arrive at 0 the value freezes.

Answer (score 0):

If you incease or decrease quantity by one then you can try below code:

```
<label for="qty"><?php echo $this->__('Qty:') ?></label>
<div class="qty_cart">
      <div class="qty-ctl">
           <button title="decrease" onclick="changeQty(0); return false;" class="decrease">decrease</button>
      </div>
      <input type="text" name="qty" id="qty" maxlength="12" value="<?php echo $this->getProductDefaultQty() * 1 ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Qty') ?>" class="input-text qty" />
      <div class="qty-ctl">
           <button title="increase" onclick="changeQty(1); return false;" class="increase">increase</button>
      </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeQty(increase) {
        var qty = parseInt($('qty').value);
        if (!isNaN(qty)) {
            qty = increase ? qty + 1 : (qty > 1 ? qty - 1 : 1);
            $('qty').value = qty;
        }
    }       
</script>
```